# Loading Bitmaps Efficiently

Tags: android, memory, bitmap

I was going through the developer.android page for loading bitmaps efficiently, and here: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html they talk about loading a Scaled Down Version into Memory, which is obviously very efficient.

Now my problem is that the given method requires the id of the resource, which we dont get (please correct me if I'm wrong here) while downloading images/bitmaps from the internet.

So is there any way we can use some variation of the given method for images which are downloaded from the internet ??

Comment: `BitmapFactory.decodeFile()` works with file paths of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey I do not know about this method but this is how I download Image from internet and save to sd card you can use this as per your requirements I use method saved to save pictures

```
public class fetchImage extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    int id;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        id = 1;// declaring static as of now

    }

    {

        new BackgroundTask().execute();
        File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File imgFile = new File(storagePath, "/Pictures/" + id + ".jpg");

        if (imgFile.exists()) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile
                    .getAbsolutePath());
        }

    }

    class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog mDialog;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(fetchImage.this, "",
                    getString(R.string.progress_bar_loading), true);
        };

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                savesd(id, null);

            } catch (final Exception e) {

            }
            return null;
        }

        private void savesd(int id, URL uri) throws IOException {
            URL url;
            if (uri == null) {
                url = new URL("http://i.zdnet.com/blogs/3-29-androids.jpg");
            } else {
                url = uri;
            }
            InputStream input = url.openStream();
            try {
                File storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                        storagePath, "/Pictures/" + id + ".jpg"));
                try {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[20000];
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = input.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) >= 0) {
                        output.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                } finally {
                    output.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                input.close();
            }

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            mDialog.dismiss();
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```